# Does the pentagon axiom force the associativity constraint to be a natural isomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

Consider a fusion ring and the associated system of polynomial equations induced by the pentagon axiom of a fusion category. A solution of this system is supposed to encode the associativity constraint $a$, i.e. a natural isomorphism given by a collection of isomorphisms $$a_{X,Y,Z}: (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z \to X \otimes (Y \otimes Z)$$ such that for all $X,Y,Z,T$, $$ a_{X,Y,Z \otimes T} \circ a_{X \otimes Y, Z, T} = (id_X \otimes a_{Y,Z,T}) \circ a_{X,Y \otimes Z, T} \circ (a_{X,Y,Z} \otimes id_T).$$

**Question**: Does the pentagon equations force every $a_{X,Y,Z}$ to be an isomorphism?

*Assumption*: To avoid any trivial answer like "take $a_{X,Y,Z} = 0$ for all $X,Y,Z$", let us consider a simplified unit axiom by assuming that if $1 \in \{X,Y,Z\}$ then $a_{X,Y,Z} = id$.

*Recursion*: By the pentagon axiom (written above), if $a_{X,Y,Z \otimes T}$ and $a_{X \otimes Y, Z, T}$ are isomorphisms, then so are $a_{Y,Z,T}$, $a_{X,Y \otimes Z, T}$, and $a_{X,Y,Z}$.

Note that the above assumption and recursion permit to prove the *pointed* case in three rounds (we removed the parentheses):

1. If $X \otimes Y = Z \otimes T = 1$ then $a_{X,Y,Z}$ and $a_{Y,Z,T}$
   are isomorphisms,
2. If $X \otimes Y \otimes Z = Y \otimes Z \otimes T = 1$ then $a_{X,Y,Z}$ and $a_{Y,Z,T}$ are isomorphisms,
3. If $X \otimes Y \otimes Z \otimes T = 1$ then $a_{X,Y,Z}$ and $a_{Y,Z,T}$ are isomorphisms.

In the third round, $a_{X,Y,Z}$ is general (for $X,Y,Z$ simple objects), the result follows.

Comment: Have you heard of skew monoidal categories? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4981.pdf These satisfy the axioms of monoidal categories, without invertibility

Comment: I don't know about fusion rings, but you can definitely have a category with a tensor product and unit which is only associative up to noninvertible associator satisfying the pentagon identity. It's called a skew-monoidal category. See the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+monoidal+category).

Comment: @TimCampion and JonasFrey:  I did not know about skew-monoidal category. That's interesting! So my question can be reformulated as whether there exists a strictly-skew-fusion category (in an appropriate sense).